# Python Dask - how to get row content on string match

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a very large dataset (>1m entries), then I have a list of postcodes and I want to loop through the postcodes and create a list of matching output areas code from the dataset.

The dataset source: https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/06938ffe68de49de98709b0c2ea7c21a/about

The code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df= dd.read_csv("PCD_OA_LSOA_MSOA_LAD_AUG19_UK_LU.csv")
zipcodes = ["AB1 5YP","AB1 7FH"]

oa11cd_output = []
for zipcode in zipcodes:
    entry = df[df['pcds'] == postcode]
    oa11cd_output.append(entry['oa11cd'])
```

however when I try to even print the entry, I do not get the actual row content but something that looks like this:

```
Name: oa11cd, dtype: object
Dask Name: getitem, 5 graph layers
dd.Scalar<size-ag..., dtype=int32>
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=6
    object
       ...
     ...  
       ...
       ...
```

Any idea how to get the actual content? Thank you

Comment: `entry['oa11cd'])` is a series. First convert to list.

Comment: If I do ```oa11cd_output.append(list(entry['oa11cd']))``` I get this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 168680: invalid continuation byte

Comment: df is a dask dataframe. Dask collections are evaluated lazily, so computation is only done when explicitly requested by calling `.compute()` or `.persist()`, or when triggered by something which needs the data values like a write, plot, or index reshuffle. To convert the results into a pandas dataframe, call `oa11cd_output.append(entry['oa11cd'].compute())`

Comment: If you actually want a list of lists not a list of series, then do `oa11cd_output.append(entry['oa11cd'].compute().tolist())`

Comment: I would strongly recommend going through the dask tutorial: https://tutorial.dask.org/01_dataframe.html. If you haven’t come across .compute() yet, jumping in and using dask dataframe is going to be rough. The tutorial will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look further into compute(), however when I try your implementation - I am still getting an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 168680: invalid continuation byte` I reckon this encoding error has something to do with the computation

Comment: This sounds like an encoding issue in your csv to me. Try to find an encoding that works - it doesn’t appear to be in utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding seems to be "iso-8859-1". On top of that the type inference does not work for two (of the) columns (in this particular file) so you have to force it. See code below:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df= dd.read_csv("PCD_OA_LSOA_MSOA_LAD_AUG19_UK_LU.csv", \
                dtype={'doterm': 'float64', 'ladnmw': 'object'}, \
                encoding="iso-8859-1")
zipcodes = ["AB1 5YP","AB1 7FH"]

oa11cd_output = []
for zipcode in zipcodes:
    entry = df[df['pcds'] == zipcode].compute().to_dict()
    oa11cd_output.append(entry['oa11cd'])
```

Some explanation on how I determined the encoding. First try was to do:

```
> file -i PCD_OA_LSOA_MSOA_LAD_AUG19_UK_LU.csv
PCD_OA_LSOA_MSOA_LAD_AUG19_UK_LU.csv: text/csv; charset=us-ascii
```

Ok, so `file` says it is us-ascii. But `file` does not read the whole file to make that evaluation (check -P parameter). I tried to increase how much `file` reads but process went out of memory. Let's try to convert it:

```
> iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 PCD_OA_LSOA_MSOA_LAD_AUG19_UK_LU.csv > converted.csv
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 198311200
```

Ok, so clearly not us-ascii. Let's output a bit around that position:

```
> tail -c +198311200 PCD_OA_LSOA_MSOA_LAD_AUG19_UK_LU.csv| head -n 10 > problem_lines.txt
> file -i problem_lines.txt
problem_lines.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Problem solved!

Comment: "the type inference does not work for two columns" - while specifying types manually is a good idea in dask, this statement isn't true. the number of columns isn't the issue - the issue is that dask uses the types returned by pandas when inspecting the first partition to infer column types. so if you have, e.g. all numeric values in the first partition and then string values in a later partition, you can end up with a value error when the whole frame is eventually read. see the notes in the [`dask.dataframe.read_csv`](//docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html) API docs

Comment: The csv has multiple columns anyhow so, what I mean (could have been more clear - adjusted the answer), the type inference does not work for "two of the multiple columns in this particular file".

Comment: I see - you're saying for this specific file. yep thanks for that clarification!